# How can I move these methods into its own class?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, class, methods

I'm new to objective c and still trying to figure out the whole objective oriented idea. In my app I have a check mark(like) button that is used in all the pages, so instead of having the check mark methods in every view, I want to move them to their own class and call them. How would I do that?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    ...

    //create check mark button
    UIButton *checkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 90)];
    //user has already check marked post
    if ([checkActivityArray containsObject:[object objectId]]){
        [checkButton setTitleColor: [UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(minusCheckMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    //user has NOT already check marked post
    else{
        [checkButton setTitleColor: [UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addCheckMark:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [checkButton setTitle:@"CH" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkButton];

    ...

    return cell;
}



 - (void)addCheckMark:(UIButton*)button{

    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    PFObject *place = [placesArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
    PFObject *checkActivity = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"activity"];
    [checkActivity setObject:place forKey:@"place"];
    [checkActivity setObject:@"checkMark" forKey:@"type"];
    [checkActivity setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"fromUser"];
    [checkActivity setObject:[place objectForKey:@"user"] forKey:@"toUser"];
    [checkActivity saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"Check marked post");

            //add post to checkActivity array
            [checkActivityArray addObject:[place objectId]];
            [checkActivityArray writeToFile:checkMarkArrayFileName atomically:YES];


            //increase check mark count
            PFObject *checkCount = [placesArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
            [checkCount incrementKey:@"checkMarkCount"];
            [checkCount saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [button tag] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:NO];
            }];
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}


    - (void)minusCheckMark:(UIButton*)button{

    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    PFObject *place = [placesArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
    PFQuery *queryCheckActivity = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
    [queryCheckActivity whereKey:@"place" equalTo:place];
    [queryCheckActivity whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"checkMark"];
    [queryCheckActivity whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [queryCheckActivity findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *activity in activities) {
                [activity delete];
            }

            //pemove post from checkActivity array
            [checkActivityArray removeObject:[place objectId]];
            [checkActivityArray writeToFile:checkMarkArrayFileName atomically:YES];

            //decrease check mark count
            PFObject *checkCount = [placesArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
            [checkCount incrementKey:@"checkMarkCount" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]];
            [checkCount saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [button tag] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:NO];
            }];
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIButon` class add it in the view where ever you need to add, & and other solution is add button to `window` or `navigation controler`.